# Как задекларировать SLOT как параметр метода класса? (в QT5)

Tags: c++, qt5, c++11

но так, чтобы использовать синтаксис указателя на функцию как в QObject::connect в версии QT5, а не (const char*):

```
connect(const QObject *sender, PointerToMemberFunction signal, const QObject *receiver, PointerToMemberFunction method, Qt::ConnectionType type)
```

Например я хочу создать функцию класса вроде этой:

```
class CommandHub : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    ...
    //эта
    void connectCommand(const QString &commandId, QObject *object, PointerToMemberFunction slot);
...
};
```

Хочу добиться вызова **connectCommand** следующим образом:

```
CommandHub commandHub;
//...
commandHub.connectCommand("open", someWidget, &SomeWidget::onOpen);
```

То есть, вопрос звучит так: что использовать вместо PointerToMemberFunction , так, чтобы можно было подставить указатель на слот объекта object?

Comment: Сделайте пример того, чего Вы хотите добиться, а то не понятно ничего.

Comment: добавил, чего хочу добиться, то есть вызов connectCommand

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете написать Вашу функцию так:

```
template <typename Sender, typename SlotType>
void connectCommand(const QString &commandId, Sender* object, SlotType slot);
```

Answer (score 1):

Все просто - берем редактор и смотрим, а как этот самый `connect` для данного случая объявлен

```
    static QMetaObject::Connection connect(const QObject *sender, const QMetaMethod &signal,
                    const QObject *receiver, const QMetaMethod &method,
                    Qt::ConnectionType type = Qt::AutoConnection);
```

То есть, тип слота имеет вид `const QMetaMethod &`.

Comment: Я не знаю точно, что спрашивает автор, но этот ответ совершенно точно не к его вопросу. У него по новому синтаксису вопрос, а у Вас ответ со старым.

Comment: Со старым там char*.

Comment: Там есть оба, в старой версии.